# Why is my Print statement not being executed?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I set up breakpoints all along my function, everything is running fine, but when it comes to the print part, it always skips over it.

```
func testForGettingAllValues(){
 let uid = user2?.id
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("user-reviews").child(uid!)
    ref.observe(.childAdded, with: {(firstSnapshot) in

        let reviewId = firstSnapshot.key
        let messageReference = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("reviews").child(reviewId)
        messageReference.queryOrdered(byChild: "ratingNumber").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(reviewSnapshot) in
            if reviewSnapshot.exists(){
                if let values = reviewSnapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject]{
                    for reviews in values {
                        if let ratingNumber = reviews.value["ratingNumber"] as? String{

                            print("This is the ratingNumber list", ratingNumber)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })

    })
}
```

}

Comment: Are all your if statements returning true? If there is no "ratingNumber" value then it won't execute the print statement, for example. Other than that, maybe it needs to be done on the main thread? `DispatchQueue.main.async`

Comment: @brimstone, print statements work from the background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In you nestedness, the following holds:

- if binding to `values` is successful, it is of type `[String:AnyObject]`
- each `reviews` instances is a named tuple of type `(key: String, value: AnyObject)`
- when you try to bind to `ratingNumber`, you access the `value` property of `reviews`, and act as if this `value` property is a dictionary itself. However, it is not, it is of type `AnyObject`.

Most likely, in the third bullet above, lies the logical error, which in turn cause the innermost optional binding to fail. The compiler cannot know whether or not the `AnyObject` instance accessible by `reviews.value` is in fact wrapping a dictionary (an `NSDictionary`, perhaps?). You could attempt to first attempt a type conversion of it to the dictionary type you believe it to be, and thereafter attempting to access the `"ratingNumber"` key of the converted value.

Possibly (without the chance to test this out myself, due to your lack of a reproducable example ...):

```
if let ratingNumber = (reviews.value as? [String: String])?["ratingNumber"]
```

Comment: I tried following your answer, but I just can't make it work. Do you have an example you can send, or what can I provide you to make a reproducible example? @dfri